# Dynamics AX - Sales Packing Slip/Invoice Posting error

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, ax

I am getting the below error whenever I try to post a Packing Slip or Invoice of a Sales Order in AX 2009. I have tried removing the tax adjustments and rearranging the orders. But even clicking the Arrange button results with the same error.

Sales orders cannot be rearranged when individual sales orders are tax regulated.
Remove the regulation on the orders, rearrange and regulate the tax on the summary order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found that there was an entry made in TaxWorkRegulation table with 0 amount. Deleted the entry and was able to post Packing Slip.